# Model not associated with Model Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

I'm trying to esatblish a One-To-Many relationship between the tables:  `Exam` and `Exam_Questions`, using Sequelize.

Even though the tables are created properly and I can see them in PhpMyAdmin, I keep getting the following error in console:

> `Error: exam_question is not associated to exam!`

#### `exam.js`

```
...
const ExamQuestion = require('./exam-question');
...

const Exam = sequelizeInstance.define("exam", {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    date: { type: Sequelize.DATE }
});

// Build the model relations
Exam.hasMany(ExamQuestion, { as: "Questions" });
```

#### `exam-question.js`

```
const ExamQuestion = Sequelize.db.define("exam_question", {
    correct_answer: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
});
module.exports = ExamQuestion;
```

To solve the error, I tried:

```
ExamQuestion.belongsTo(Exam);
```

But that doesn't change anything.

The query is:

```
Exam.findAll({
     include: [ExamQuestion]
})
```

How to fix this problem and get the Exam objects including their questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

For some very non-intuitive reason this seems to be happening because of the `as` property. To fix the problem, simply remove the `as` property:

```
Exam.hasMany(ExamQuestion);
```

### Fixing the methods

By default, after removing the `as` property, Sequelize will automagically add the following methods: `getExam_questions`, `addExam_question` and so on.

They look quite bad: camel and snake cases mixed up together.

To solve that, we can easily define the `singular` and `plural` names in the `ExamQuestion` model options (the third argument):

```
const ExamQuestion = Sequelize.db.define("exam_question", {
    correct_answer: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    text: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
}, {
    name: {
        singular: "question",
        plural: "questions"
    }
});
```

This will dictate Sequelize to create methods such as `getQuestions` and `addQuestion` instead of `getExam_questions` and `addExam_question`.